# How do i set AWS S3 with AWS SNS for upload event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I want to use event notification which is one of the basic functions of AWS S3 and AWS SNS.
Setting the event in S3 raises the following warning.

“Unable to validate the following destination configurations. Permissions on the destination topic do not allow S3 to publish notifications from this bucket”

So I go to the S3 policy generator.

```html
 {
  "Id": "Policy1571877681758",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1571877676943",
      "Action": "sns:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": “mysnsarn”,
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

but there’s some error like this “Policy has invalid action”

i don’t know what to do..

Comment: I'd say it's the curly quotes around `“mysnsarn”` that are causing the problem.

Comment: I believe you need to add SNS topic policy. You can refer this link that has more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems in the json:

1. The quotes in resource value is wrong
2. Principal filed is not allowed (as this is a role policy)
3. Leading spaces in json

A corrected version of your policy, which is reviewd to be good in IAM looks like this:

```
{ 
   "Id":"Policy1571877681758",
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[ 
      { 
         "Sid":"Stmt1571877676943",
         "Action":"sns:*",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":"yourSNSARNHere"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks working great. I've been changing the S3's policy, and I know I have to change the SNS's policy. Thank you.